# docking and changing width replaces docked forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, docking

I'm currently working on a Windows Forms Application that is essentially a bunch of forms laid on top of each other. Right now, I have this...

- MainForm - MDI Parent
- ChildForm - Dock set to 'Fill' in MainForm
- Sidebar1 - Dock set to 'Left' in MainForm
- Sidebar2 - Dock set to 'Right' in MainForm - able to be resized
- ChildChildform - Dock set to 'fill' in MainForm, overtop of Childform

So here's my issue - since Sidebar2 is able to be resized widthwise, I figured it would work fine to throw a button on that does the resize for me - push a button, it slides in, push a button, it slides out - kind of like a slide out on screen keyboard. However, when I slide this out while ChildChildForm is up, ChildChildform dissappears and it goes back to displaying  Childform.

My best guess is that since ChildForm and Sidebar1 are both set to MDIParent = MainForm, it's displaying on ChildForm First, since ChildChildForm is set to MDIParent = Mainform, but it's the second one...

Anyone have any tips on how to roll the sidebar in to the topmost form if that topmost form is an MDIChild?

Comment: MDI Child Forms should have their WindowState set to Maximized in your scenario.

Comment: Might not be what you're looking for, but I have used a 3rd party solution called `DockPanel` which gave me basically a Visual Studio 2005 look and feel with docking, pinning, resizing, etc. http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/